# How can I get the primary keys of all records in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have inserted plenty of data into Cassandra. Now I'd like to randomly query one record.
But I don't know the `primary key`. So I want a way to fetch the primary keys of `all data` in Cassandra，then I can use one random primary key to query the data.

Can I get it from the `data` directory of Cassandra? I only found .db files in that directory.

Comment: There is no such functionality... May be you can try `COPY table_name(column_name) TO file_name.csv`

Comment: Can I get the primary keys from `data` directory using some tools?

Comment: this COPY command will work in DevCenter as well as cqlsh... Data directory will contain only part of data (data distributed on different nodes)

Comment: sstable2json utility will give you complete data dump of ssTable file you specify

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Cassandra are you on?  If you're on Cassandra 3, you could query system_schema.columns from the command line, and grep for the PRIMARY KEY parts like this:

```
$ bin/cqlsh -u aploetz -p pass 
    -e'SELECT keyspace_name,table_name,column_name,kind 
       FROM system_schema.columns' | grep _key
               test |                           fail |                          id | partition_key
      stackoverflow |                 hourly_average |              application_id | partition_key
      stackoverflow |                         meters |                   device_id | partition_key
      stackoverflow |                         meters |                  parking_id | partition_key
      stackoverflow |                        meters2 |                   device_id | partition_key
      stackoverflow |                        meters2 |                  parking_id | partition_key
```

Then to get the clustering keys, you could modify that slightly:

```
$ bin/cqlsh -u aploetz -p pass
    -e'SELECT keyspace_name,table_name,column_name,kind
       FROM system_schema.columns' | grep clustering
      stackoverflow |                 hourly_average |                   device_id |    clustering
      stackoverflow |                 hourly_average |                 location_id |    clustering
      stackoverflow |                 hourly_average |                  partner_id |    clustering
      stackoverflow |                         meters |                        date |    clustering
      stackoverflow |                         meters |                      status |    clustering
      stackoverflow |                        meters2 |                        date |    clustering
      stackoverflow |                        meters2 |                      status |    clustering
```

Note that if you want to filter these results by keyspace and table, you can specify those in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I don't want the schema of the primary keys. What I want to get is the value of the primary keys.

Answer (score 3):

To get the primary key values you can use distinct in CQL:

```
cqlsh> select distinct pkey_column FROM table;
```

Or with multiple:

```
cqlsh> select distinct pkey_column_1, pkey_column_2 FROM table;
```

Comment: what should I query `pkey_colum` if I already know its name? We need the name of its primary key column name like `id`, `mytable_id` or anything else.

Comment: @Badiparmagi You can use `DESCRIBE TABLE keyspace_name.table_name` to see what are the primary key columns of a specific table (or use @Aaron's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [TOKEN](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html) function in order to avoid unbound `SELECT * FROM xxx;` queries. [This external post](http://www.myhowto.org/bigdata/2013/11/04/scanning-the-entire-cassandra-column-family-with-cql/) explains how to traverse all your dataset, but you can adopt it to your use case with very small efforts.