# How to read only all row keys in cassandra efficiently...

Tags: cassandra

Accessing all rows from all nodes in cassandra would be inefficient. Is there a way to have some access to index.db which already has row keys? is something of this sort supported in built in cassandra?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get all keys with one request without reaching every node in the cluster. There is however paging built-in in most Cassandra drivers. For example in the Java driver: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/manual/paging/

This will put less stress on each node as it only fetches a limit amount of data each request. Each subsequent request will continue from the last, meaning you will touch every result for the request you're making.

Edit: This is probably what you want: [How can I get the primary keys of all records in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289008/how-can-i-get-the-primary-keys-of-all-records-in-cassandra)

Comment: we can request for only keys - but it would require scanning memtable and multiple SStables which would be slow, whereas all row key information is available in index.db. that's the reason i thought if we could get index.db or cassandra had some mechanism to get info directly from index.db,  that would be way faster?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand the question first. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option could be querying all the token ranges. 
For example,

```
SELECT distinct <partn_col_name> FROM <table_name> where token(partn_col_name) >= <from_token_range> and token(partn_col_name) < <to_token_range>
```

With above query, you can get the all the partition keys available within given token range. Adjust token ranges depending on execution time.